# How to User sales_order_place_after for Recurring Profile

Tags: magento

I am using sales_order_place_after event in observer event

```
<sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                   <Test_Check_Model_Observer>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>Test_Check_Model_Observer</class>
                      <method>SubscribePlan</method>
                   </Test_Check_Model_Observer>
               </observers>
</sales_order_place_after>
```

Then My Observer.php's Method SubscribePlan Contains

```
public function SubscribePlan($observer) { 



        die('getting called');


    }
```

This event is Working but when i Place Order for Recurring Profile this event doesn't work, Can some one please Tell me any alternate event which also works for recurring profile after placing order

Answer (score 0):

Here the code

```
<global>
    <models>
        <test>
            <class>Test_Check_Model</class>
        </test>
    </models>
    <events>
            <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <mysales_order_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>test/observer</class>
                    <method>SubscribePlan</method>
                </mysales_order_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>



        </events>
</global>
```

Comment: It doesn't work when i place order for recurring profile

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for something similar recently and my solution is

> 1. override model Mage_Sales_Model_Recurring_Profile with your own model
> 2. Inside your own model, set property $_eventPrefix to for example "recurring_profile"
> 3. create observer for event recurring_profile_save_commit_after.

If you need exactly the event when profile is created, you may need to override submit method and either dispatch a customized event or just put all code there without using event/observer at all.

P.S. I used Magento 1.9.3.2